# Compute inverse polynomial over Finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

I want to know how to compute this, All this polynomials are over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$.

I have that

$$ (x^6 + x^4 + x^3)^{-1} \equiv x^4 + x^3 \mod(x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) $$

Where $m(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ is the Rijndael polynomial. But I don't know how to compute this.

Comment: What you are claiming is equivalent to $(x^6 + x^4 + x^3)(x^4 + x^3) \equiv 1$ mod the given Rijndael polynomial $m(x)$.  So you can test this claim by multiplication of polynomials (and reduction mod $m(x)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Use the extended Euclidean algorithm for $\gcd(x^6 + x^4 + x^3,x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1)$ and express $1=(x^6 + x^4 + x^3)p(x)+(x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1)q(x)$. Then you can interpret $p(x)$ as the desired inverse.